# Vue3 provide/inject type boolean with ref not working

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

In parentComponent, provide a testboolean ref.

```
<script lang="ts">
mounted() {
    let testboolean = ref<boolean>(true);
    provide('test', testboolean)
}
</script>
```

In childrenComponent, inject this above. Also click the div to change testboolean.

```
<script setup>
    import { inject } from 'vue';
    let testboolean = inject('test', false);
    function toggleControlbox(){
        testboolean = !testboolean;
    }
</script>
<template>
    <div @click.stop.prevent="toggleControlbox()">{{ testboolean }}</div>
</template>
```

In function toggleControlbox, the testboolean is working normally, output true/false, false/true ..

But in page, which code in tamplate nothing change. Still showing false.

testboolean in page change when click.

Answer (score 0):

1. the code you've got in your parent component's `mounted` hook needs to be outside of it if you are using `<script setup lang="ts">` there too.
2. I imagine that if you have `provide('test', testboolean)` in parent component then the inject code should have the same name: e.g. `let testboolean = inject('test', false);`

Comment: Yes I repair with your advance. I found inject key should the same with provide, still not working... But provide a string is fine , instead boolean.